# Hair particle system as dynamic paint brush not working?

Tags: modeling, particles, hair, dynamic-paint

I am trying to create a moving paintbrush effect using dynamic paint (in Blender 2.79).  A particle system of "hair" type is the brush and a subdivided plane is the canvas.  The notion is to have each brush hair/bristle paint individually, so that using collision physics the brush shape will deform as it is dragged across the canvas, and the dynamic paint will reflect that.

However I'm darned if I can get the hair particle system to paint anything!  If I change the particle system to the "emitter" type it works as expected, so I think I have the basic dynamic paint setup correct.  But no matter how I modify the brush settings the canvas is unmarked when the particle system is set to hair (e.g. modifying the particle effect solid radius under "Dynamic Paint Source", checking/unchecking "use particle's radius").  This is even true if the hair system is rendering objects (little bristle strand objects) rather than paths.

Maybe this is a bug, maybe it's just not implemented, maybe I'm missing some necessary setting?  Would appreciate any guidance!

Note: although I have the collision / deformation working, I've turned it off while I'm trying to get the dynamic paint working.

UPDATE: well I have still had no luck with the hair particle system.  The best I've been able to do is convert the hairs to curves, then to a mesh, and use cloth physics to model the deformation.  Preliminarily it comes out something like I wanted, although getting the cloth physics right is a challenge.

[image]

Still: it would be much handier to do all this with the hair particle system!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Particle Instance** modifier.

I used *Cylinder* as basic mesh, which was instanced via another object's *Hair* system.

So, this Instanced mesh will be a *Dynamic Paint Brush*, set brush option to *Mesh Volume* or *Mesh Volume + Proximity* to get it work.

[image]

Default *Cylinder* is vertically oriented, but I gave it 90 degree rotation on X axis in *Edit* mode (note, that you should do transforms in *Edit* mode, otherwise transformations will affect whole instanced object). Add some loopcuts to make it easier to bend along hair strands.

*Cylinder* in *Edit* mode:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!   I did get this to work in the sense of the weight paint, although getting the collisions to work has been trickier . . . I can't seem to get the cloth/collision simulation going for the hairs, but that may just require some messing around.

Answer (score 0):

I have been on this exact same quest and I also have not got hair painting or collision to work, would like to see your cloth settings, I have tried it and it was horrible, tried hair cards, converting to mesh, not sure it is possible in blender for all those bristles to have collision. best one I have come across so far, not many of us out there :) and I have still to get the paint working, gonna use what I learned here and hope it works

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Is this an answer or is this a question?